# XCode project template with custom framework

Tags: frameworks, xcode4, project-template

I am trying to create project template in **XCode 4.3.2** that will include custom framework. I want to include **QuincyKit.framework** to my project template to enable crash reporting. Is there way how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap's template](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-iphone/blob/475e82ec5a603621990095917d441465404a2d39/PhoneGap-based%20Application.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist) does it by simply referencing the absolute path of their framework within the `Definitions` section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    [...]

    <key>Definitions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PhoneGap</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>/Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework</string>
            <key>PathType</key>
            <string>Absolute</string>
        </dict>
```

Additionally, they reference that framework's path within the `Targets` under `SharedSettings` section;

```
    [...]

    <key>Targets</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SharedSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS</key>
                <string>YES</string>
                <key>FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS</key>
                <string>/Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

That does the job but is ugly as hell. I would prefer to not use absolute paths but that implies other tasks to get done - like running a script once the template is used - for that part, I do not have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has probably resolved itself without ever getting an answer here on SO. But my suggestion by now would be to include a [CocoaPods](http://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) `Podfile` in your project template, like the [Xcode Project Templates of AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/Xcode-Project-Templates), that refers to QuincyKit.

After creating the template, all you need to do in the terminal is run `pod install`. Not fully automatic, but it gets the job done.